# Adding ID in second Table

Tags: mysql, php

I have two table one is `photos` and another one is `photo_detail`, this is how i have created both tables:

```
/* creating photos table */
CREATE TABLE photos(
->  pid INT(10) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
->  purl VARCHAR(200) NOT NULL,
->  uid INT(5) NOT NULL,
->  time TIMESTAMP NOT NULL,
->  title VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
->  PRIMARY KEY (pid)
->  )
->  ENGINE = InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;

/* creating photo_detail table */

CREATE TABLE photodetail(
->  pid INT(6) NOT NULL,
->  ptext TEXT NOT NULL,
->  location VARCHAR(40) NOT NULL,
->  FOREIGN KEY (pid) REFERENCES photos(pid)
->  )
->  ENGINE = Innodb DEFAULT CHARSET = utf8;
```

My question is how i can add the automatically incremented ID from `photos` table to `photo_detail` table  while storing the photo? i am using PHP language! any suggestion on this table design?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [**LAST_INSERT_ID()**](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_last-insert-id) to get the inserted id for example if you insert a row in your photos table and you need that auto incremented id for the detail table you can do so

```
INSERT INTO photos (purl, uid,`time`,title)
VALUES ( 'test',1,1111,'test');
INSERT INTO photodetail (pid, ptext, location)
VALUES (LAST_INSERT_ID(), 'test', 'test');
```

### [Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/2f37e5/2)